# Font from origin Error on Apache

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, controls

I am getting the console error

```
Font from origin 'http://mycssandjsfiles.myurl.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://myurl.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Steps I Have done so far:

```
sudo a2enmod headers
```

Added to Both Directories to my .htaccess files

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

In Terminal:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I'm Not Sure what else I need to do. Any Ideas ?